# How do I manipulate an Android View with WebAppInterface (Javascript interface)?

Tags: javascript, android

I'm using WebAppInterface to grab data from Javascript while my Android WebView is running. How do I manipulate my Android View's right after I get some data from my Javascript?

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    //This function can only be called by javascript
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void sendDataToJava(float currTime, String url) {

        videoUrl = url;
        videoTime = Math.round(currTime);

        //use references to views to change stuff
        videoView.seekTo(videoTime); //ERROR HERE
       //ERROR: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to your view's containing activity, and invoke your view-related code with the activity.runOnUiThread method using a runnable.

It'll look something like this:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;
    Activity mActivity;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c, Activity a) {
        mContext = c;
        mActivity = a;

    }

    //This function can only be called by javascript
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
    public void sendDataToJava(float currTime, String url) {

        videoUrl = url;
        videoTime = Math.round(currTime);

        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                videoView.seekTo(videoTime); 
            }
        });
    }

}
```